# SPI communication using MSP-EXP430FF5529LP

Tags: spi, msp430, energia

I am using SPI communication for the first time using Energia IDE (similar to Arduino IDE) to a gas sensor. However I get FF's as output.

I have tried connecting MISO to MOSI line to check what is wrong but MOSI line seems to send 11111's and the MISO line shows FF's.

I have attached the pictures of the read debug register which i want to read from.The output as shown should be 0A1. I have tried reading the value from LabView before which works fine.

Could anyone please tell me what's wrong with my code? How can I display the sensor output in the serial monitor?

[image]

[image]

```c
#include <SPI.h>
const int chipSelectPin = 33; // P2.0
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
   SPISettings SettingsA(100000,MSBFIRST,SPI_MODE0);
  SPI.setClockDivider(SPI_CLOCK_DIV8); 
}

void loop() {
  byte result;

   pinMode(chipSelectPin, OUTPUT);
   SPI.begin();
    
    //SPI.setBitOrder(MSBFIRST);
  //SPI.setDataMode(SPI_MODE0); 
   digitalWrite(chipSelectPin, LOW);
   //sending command to the debug register
   SPI.transfer(242);
   SPI.transfer(00);
  SPI.transfer(00);
   SPI.transfer(00);
   SPI.transfer(00);
   result=SPI.transfer(00);
   delay(1);
  digitalWrite(chipSelectPin, HIGH);
  
  Serial.println(result,HEX);
  
 }
```

[image]

Comment: PAllavi - Welcome :-) I don't use the Energia framework, but there is an obvious missing `}` to end the `setup()` function. Is that really missing in your code, or is that a mistake in your copy & paste? (I added the " ``` " code fence syntax so that your code displays correctly, but I didn't remove any `}` characters.) What troubleshooting have you done e.g. using a scope or logic analyser to view the SPI bus? Please [Edit] the question and link to the datasheet for the SPI sensor. Please also add your schematic and a photo of your hardware. Thanks.

Comment: Nobody can tell what's wrong with your code or even IF there's anything (non-trivial like } wrong, as opposed to a hardware issue. This is where you start debugging. Personally I'd have a scope on those SPI signals to see which are working and which aren't.

Comment: To send a command and then receive the answer, you need two transfers.

Comment: I have tried to receive data from slave using interrupts but it's not working.I connected the MOSI to MISO just to check if the data is being sent.But the output shows FF's .I didn't upload the schematic because I am working on the sensor which is being developed by company  so I am not sure I am allowed to put it out. Does anyone know how to display the output which is being sent to the slave? How do I access the value which is stored in the register ?

Comment: I need to send the values to the F2 register and retrieve the data from it. thanks for the reply.I will try everyone's suggestions and get back to you.Thank you guys!

Comment: @PAllavi - Hi, I didn't see answers to any of my questions, except that you said you won't supply a schematic as it is company-confidential :-( You even asked questions which were effectively answered e.g. you asked how to see what is being sent to the slave on SPI, and I already said about using a scope or logic analyzer to view what is on the SPI bus. Please respond to *all* the points raised so far, to avoid your question being closed. Thanks.

Comment: Also,I have tried using logic analyser .I can only see the chipselect working perfectly fine but MOSI line giving garbage values. and the clock speed very high despite me setting it to 1MHZ. I just need to read the ID from a debug register. I will try to attach pictures.

Comment: I have tried attaching the screenshots above. Is it possible to read the value of debug register? I have solved the erros in the program and now my program compiles fine . but I still get ff's.

Comment: I hope I am a bit clear with my question!